# Puzzle: for boolean matrix find permutation of rows and colums that allows decomposistion into minimal set of covering rectangles

Tags: algorithm

Suppose I know an algorithm, that partitions a boolean matrix into a minimal set of disjoint rectangles that cover all "ones" ("trues"). 
The task is to find a permutation of rows and columns of the matrix, such that a matrix built by shuffling the columns and rows according to the permutations can be partitioned into a minimal set of rectangles.

For illustration, one can think about the problem this way:

> Suppose I have a set of objects and a set of properties. Each object can have any number of (distinct) properties. The task is to summarize (report) this mapping using the least amount of sentences. Each sentence has a form "`<list of objects> have properties <list of properties>`".

I know I can brute-force the solution by applying the permutations and run the algorithm on each try. But the time complexity explodes exponentially making this approach non-practical for matrices bigger than 15×15.

I know I can simplify the matrices before running the algorithm by removing duplicated rows and columns.

This problem feels like it is NP-hard, and there might be no fast (polynomial in time) solutions. If that is so, I'd be interested to learn about some approximate solutions.

Comment: Just to check -- those rectangles can overlap each other, as long as they don't include any `0` entries.  Correct?

Comment: @Prune. At the moment I try to write an algorithm that prevents overlaps, but I am open to a solution when they can. I understand, that logic optimization approach would yield overlaps, and that is OK with me. Added bonus is that it could also naturally give negatives in the output  (i.e. `all objects except for A, B and C has properties a and b`).

Answer (score 1):

This is isomorphic to reducing logic circuits, given the full set of inputs (features) and the required truth table (which rows have which feature).  You can solve the problem with classic Boolean algebra.  The process is called [logic optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_optimization#Circuit_minimization_in_Boolean_algebra).

When I was in school, we drew [Karnaugh maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) on the board and drew colored boundaries to form our rectangles.  However, it sounds as if you have something larger than one would handle on the board; try the [QM algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm) and the cited heuristics for a "good enough" solution for many applications.

Comment: I thought about your idea a lot, and still can't see the isomorphism. Assuming you mean multilevel logic (where the binary expression has an output that is a vector of booleans, and each dimension of the output is mapped to the object, and each input variable is mapped to the feature) my problem is symmetric - you can swap objects with features and still get the same (but transposed) solution whereas afaik the logic optimization is not symmetric to the swapping between input and output variables. Or maybe I am wrong - it is not my field of expertise.

Comment: Okay ... it's *my* turn to think ... I'm going to bounce my ideas off a few friends who work with these things more often.

Comment: For now ... the place where I see the isomorphism is not in the final result, but in the algorithm.  To get the minimal logic, you have to switch rows and columns, such that the `1` bits are clustered into nice rectangular groupings.  Then you identify the minimal set of rectangles to cover all the `1`s without including any `0`s.  Producing the and/or logic is the final step ... and is *not* part of my proposed  isomorphism.

Comment: I have updated the question so it incorporates my current work on the problem. And thanks a lot for your effort.

Comment: Good work.  I had to do my own research this weekend, but determined that the problem is, indeed, isomorphic to the logic solution.

Comment: Could you please help me with the isomorphism? 1. Do you mean multilevel logic optimizer? 2. What entity is isomorphic to the features, and what entity is isomorphic to the objects? BTW, I have upgraded my own solution, it is now much faster, and yields much better results.

Comment: (1) If your solution is working well, don't worry about mine.  Working code beats theory any day.  (2) The entity mapping can go either way, since the relationships are bidirectional.  I'll try to work through the algorithm when I get some time free from work and home\ duties.

Comment: thank you. Your approach can be potentially much more optimal since it is not restricted by the condition that the rectangles must be non-overlapping.

Comment: I just got to bounce the idea off my "consulting team".  The approach looks reasonable to them, but I still have to do the applied thinking.

Answer (score 0):

My solution so far:

First let us acknowledge, that the problem is symmetric with respect to swapping rows with columns (features with objects).

Let us represent the problem with the binary matrix, where rows are objects and columns are features and ones in the matrix represent matched pairs (object, feature).

My idea so far is to run two steps in sequence until there is no 1s left in the matrix:

1. Heuristically find a good unshuffling permutation of rows and columns on which I can run 2D maximal rectangle
2. Find the maximal rectangle, save it to the answer list and zero all 1s belonging to it.

#### Maximal rectangle problem

It can be simply any of the implementations of the maximal rectangle problem found on the net, for instance https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-size-rectangle-binary-sub-matrix-1s/

### Unshuffling the rows (and columns)

Unshuffling rows are independent of unshuffling columns and both tasks can be run separately (concurrently). Let us assume I am looking for the unshuffling permutation of columns.

Also, it is worth noting, that unshuffling a matrix should yield the same results if we swap ones with zeroes.

1. Build a distance matrix of columns. A distance between two columns is defined as Manhattan distance between the two columns represented numerically (i.e. 0 - the absence of a relationship between object and feature, 1 - presence)
2. Run hierarchical clustering using the distance matrix. The complexity is O(n^2), as I believe single linkage should be good enough.
3. The order of objects returned from the hierarchical clustering is the unshuffling permutation.

The algorithm works good enough for my use cases. The implementation in R can be found in https://github.com/adamryczkowski/rectpartitions